# Finding second highest number logic explanation

Tags: sql, database

I need bit explanation on finding second highest valued column using query below

```
SELECT MAX( column )
  FROM table
 WHERE column < ( SELECT MAX( column )
                 FROM table )
```

assume i have a `table` with `single column` named as `'column'` and it has values `10,20,30,40.`

now my above query outputs `30` which is second highest anyway.

this is how it works as per my understanding.

inner query finds the `MAX( column )` and it is `40` always in my case.

now for each column using `WHERE` we are checking whether its less than `max` value.

but how we store that result to find the `MAX(column)` using `outer query` ?

means somewhere we should have a `list of values lesser than actual max value ie 40` in my case.

and that list would be `10,20,30`.

and again we are finding `max` out of this list which is `30`.

```
 so here how and where it stores all the columns lesser than actual max value

(40 in this case) which is used at the end to find 

 max again using that list(10,20,30).
```

can any one explain me how this works ?

Comment: How it excludes..dont you think this is how it evalautes literally speaking... SELECT MAX( column ) FROM table inner query returns 40 ...but outer query SELECT MAX( column ) also returns 40 always right  ? means outer query works in this way right -> SELECT MAX( column ) FROM table WHERE column < 40 , always 40 where 10 < 40, 40 where 20< 40 and 40 where 30 < 40...? how it gets the expected evaluation?

Comment: tell me one thing what will be the  MAX( column ) in outer query for every column it fires with where condition..

Comment: I don't understand the question.  IN the case of set {10,20,30,40} the sub-select it will return 40 (the select in the where clause).  The main select will then be limited by the results of the sub select so while the main select without a where would return {10,20,30,40} it's then evaluated to exclude anything less than the max (40) thus the set becomes {10,20,30} and it is from this set that the max is select.  Now if your set was {10,20,30,40,40} the result of your query would still be 30.  It's technically not the 2nd highest since there is a tie for first.

Comment: see i got what you are trying to explain but in outer query we have select max(column) not just column to get the set of numbers right so it should become like 40 where 10 < 40 for first column and 40 where 20< 40 for 2nd and 40 where 30 < 40 for 3rd one right ?

Comment: 'we have select max(column) not just column to get the set of numbers right' Kind of.  The select max(column) to get the set of numbers is operating on a diminished set already due to the where clause.  So instead of getting a max from {10,20,30,40} it's getting a max from {10,20,30} because the 10<40, 20<40, 20<30, 40<40 has already been applied to the original set.  Yielding a sub set which the max will be applied against.

Comment: anyway i am bit satisfied with your explanation..lets try to explore more on it...thanks for your time..

Answer (score 1):

This is how the query is logically evaluated.

T (c) => { 10, 20, 30, 40 }

MAX(c) => 40

SELECT c FROM T WHERE c < 40 => { 10, 20, 30 }

SELECT MAX(c) FROM T WHERE c < 40 => 30

Comment: The only comment I would have here is the second select from the bottom should contain 40 in the set.  It's returned and then excluded by the where before max is evaluated.

Comment: No it should not, the set of elements c from T that is less than 40 does not contain 40

Comment: How come this query is formed SELECT c FROM T WHERE c < 40 => { 10, 20, 30 }..no where we have returned like that for select..

Comment: Not sure I understand your question here, but I suspect that some of the confusion depends on the fact that you are not thinking in sets. Instead you are trying to grasp what is happening in terms of loops and return statements. The elements c from T that is less than 40 is {10,20,30}.

Answer (score 0):

You have two queries here:
`SELECT MAX( column )
 FROM table`
This finds the largest row in the column and returns it.

`SELECT MAX( column )
 FROM table
 WHERE column <...`
This finds the largest row in the column that is less than some condition

By their powers combined...

`SELECT MAX( column )
 FROM table
 WHERE column < (SELECT MAX( column )
 FROM table)`
This finds the largest row in the column that is less than the largest row in the column (aka the second largest).

Answer (score 0):

I see you understand this query, don't you?:

```
SELECT MAX( column )
FROM table
```

It simply returns max value stored in this table. So it is `40` in your example.

So now consider this query that simplifies issue a bit:

```
SELECT MAX( column )
FROM table
WHERE column < 40
```

I don't see any problems for you to understand this either. It is still the same query as above, but only considering rows that `column` value is less then `40`. How exactly it is stored in database (as temporary table etc.) is problem of DBMS and you don't need to trouble yourself about it.

Please specify what exactly do not you understand and expect from us to clarify.

Comment: SELECT MAX( column )
FROM table inner query returns 40 i too know this sir as i stated in question....but outer query SELECT MAX( column ) also returns 40 always right ? means outer query works in this way right -> SELECT MAX( column )
FROM table
WHERE column < 40   , always 40 where 10 < 40, 40 where 20< 40 and 40 where 30 < 40...?

Comment: The WHERE clause is part of the query; it is not a separate statement. SQL has no statements; it is a declarative language. MAX is determined _after_ WHERE has reduced the set of rows.

Comment: `SELECT MAX( column ) FROM table WHERE column < 40` FIRSTLY returns all rows that meet the `WHERE` clause (so in our case rows with values `10, 20, 30` and then looks for `MAX` value from all that rows that remained (so here `30` is maximum of this three)

Answer (score 0):

The inner query selects the top value from the table. The RDBMS is smart enough to hold this value in memory, then hit the table again looking for the top value from the table, except this time it's looking for the top value that's smaller than the original top value.

There's not much more too it than that. I didn't write the RDBMS, so I don't know exactly how it operates.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 2;

This will provide the top two, so you will need to parse the data from there.

Comment: i know there are many other approaches to find 2nd highest number, but i need explanation on my above query...